# How to pass a string as a parameter of query

Tags: mysql, c

I have a variable `Name`, that is going to receive a value from `cmd/terminal`, and I'm trying to pass this variable as a parameter to a query command.

I've already tried these:
`'"+Name+"', :Name, @Name, +Name, DESCRIBE, #define @Name, Values(%s),Name),...`

C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <my_global.h>
#include <mysql.h>

void finish_with_error(MYSQL *con)
{
  fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(con));
  mysql_close(con);
  exit(1);        
}
int main()
{ 
    printf("Enter a name ");

    int n = 0;
    char c;

    char *Name = NULL;

    do
    {
        Name = (char*)realloc(Name, (++n) * sizeof(char));
        Name[n-1] = (c = getchar()) == '\n' ? '\0' : c;

    }while(c != '\n');

    MYSQL *con = mysql_init(NULL);

    if (con == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(con));
        exit(1);
    }

    if (mysql_real_connect(con, "localhost", "root", "YES", "Users", 0, NULL, 0) == NULL)
    {
        finish_with_error(con);
    }

    /*I WANNA PASS THE VARIABLE Name TO THIS QUERY -> VALUES(NAME)*/
    if (mysql_query(con, "INSERT INTO Personal_info (First_name) VALUES()")); 
    {
        finish_with_error(con);
    }

    return 0;
```

I want to put in the query command the value of that variable.

To all code that I've tried, I receive the same error message:

```
syntax error
```

Comment: I don't know well, but this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36266635/mysql-c-api-parameterized-query-fetch-result

Comment: Can you post a complete example that produces the error? Also, which language? `C` or `C++`?

Comment: I've updated the code

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
snprintf(buf,sizeof(buf),"INSERT INTO Personal_info (First_name) VALUES(%s)",Name);
if(mysql_query(con, buf))
```

Warning: Just off the top of my head, not actually compiled and tested!

Comment: Thank you, but I've already tried this one and didn't work.
its point to the beginning  of Name and says, error: expected expression before ‘}’